# Prevent form submission using react and e.preventDefault();

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't seem to figure this out.... 
Which event makes sense to bind a function call on to action e.preventDefault(); in the event that someone clicks enter when they fill in the input tag?

At the moment i get an unwanted refresh happening. When i just want to trigger another function when the enter key is hit.

What should i do?

```
<form onSubmit={this.stopSubmit}>
                        <FormGroup
                            controlId="formBasicText"
                            validationState={getValidationState()}
                        >
                            <ControlLabel>Stuff</ControlLabel>
                            <FormControl
                                type="text"
                                value={this.state.value}
                                placeholder="Enter text"
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                onKeyUp={handleSubmit.bind(this, "test")}

                            />
                            <FormControl.Feedback/>
                            <HelpBlock>Validation is based on string length.</HelpBlock>
                        </FormGroup>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

`this.stopSubmit` should return `false` to prevent the form submission

Answer (score 1):

add this to the form tag:

```
<form onSubmit={e => { e.preventDefault(); }}>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem so it may help other users. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

The event is the form submission. You can read up on it at [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit).

Really it depends on what your form is doing. Usually you will put your `event.preventDefault()` function call in whatever you're submitting your form to.(ie: what the value of the `action` parameter is) If its an AJAX call, for instance, you'll want to put that at the beginning of the function.

At least, thats what I do. Here is an example of a recent function I used for a form submission that utilizes it.

```
handleFormSubmit = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.searchMovies(this.state.search);
};
```